# Getting a null result scraping a xmtml

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new using scrapy a i got a null result with this page. I tried to crawl this page https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/finca-raiz/arrendamientos/medellin/ in orden to get information about prices, sizes an ubication of the properties in Medellin, but I could it.

I tried to find some nodes however shell only shows me the information i requested doesn´t exist. Following shell in that page there only html tags.

I used this in orden to get some result but it doesn't work

```
response.css('*').getall()
```

This is the actual result

```
[<Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::*' data='<html></html>'>]
```

and this

```
['<html></html>']
```

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code your expected results and the actual result, and a snippet of the htmls you are trying to scrape.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup `User-Agent` header to get correct response:

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/finca-raiz/arrendamientos/medellin/
```

Just edit your `settings.py`:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'
```

After that you'll be able to get all properties URLs:

```
response.xpath('//a[.//h2]/@href').getall()
```